# Right design for a command that closes the caller window?

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, command

I've got a WPF dialog (inheritor of Window). The dialog has an "OK" button that is bound to a "process" command on the ViewModel. (The "process" command is a Josh Smith RelayCommand.) The CommandParameter on the "OK" button is set to the dialog window itself. If the processing succeeds the dialog window is closed from inside the ViewModel's command handler. That seems like a violation of the Single Responsibility principle to me. What's the right pattern for a Command that may or may not close the caller window?

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems like some design patterns are broken, its common practice that a ViewModel may be aware of its View in order to achieve specific tasks such as closing a dialog or setting a specific state.

During View-ViewModel binding, the ViewModel can be initialized with a reference to the View. Later on by executing the Command, the ViewModel can use functionality which is provided by the view using a common interface.

In your case I suggest to do it this way (like [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) does) rather than passing the Window as `CommandParameter`.

Comment: So Caliburn.Micro uses class naming conventions to locate the view. I'm not sure I like that either. I like your idea of passing in the view at construction time, but that brings a follow-up question. Typically I like to construct the ViewModel class in the Resources section of the view. I like that because I get Intellisense for the ViewModel properties in the XAML. Is there a good way to construct these things in XAML while still supporting an IoC-type of initialization of the ViewModel?